# Getting an "Stale element reference" When trying to loop through pages with the intention of scraping multiple pages

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, webdriver, screen-scraping

I'm having an issue with my Python code. The intension is to use Selenium to open up the website (craigslist), search a text (Honda) then scrape three pages of this site. I keep getting the

"StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document" exception

when the iteration reaches the second page. I cant exactly tell why its stopping at the second page and not clicking the "next" button once more to reach the third page then finally scraping the data and printing it.

This is my code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


DRIVER_PATH = "/Users/mouradsal/Downloads/DataSets Python/chromedriver"
URL = "https://vancouver.craigslist.org/"

browser = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER_PATH)
browser.get(URL)
browser.maximize_window()

time.sleep(4)

search = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#query")
search.send_keys("Honda")
search.send_keys(u'\ue007')


content = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".hdrlnk")

button = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".next")

for i in range(0,3):
    button.click()
    print("Count: "+ str(i))
    time.sleep(10)
print("done loop ")

for e in content:
    start = e.get_attribute("innerHTML")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(start, features=("lxml"))
    print(soup.get_text())
    print("***************************")
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(0,3):
    button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".next")
    button.click()
    print("Count: "+ str(i))
    time.sleep(10)
```

You need to nest your finding of elements cause webelements change every time you get to a new page.

Comment: Hi, that worked to get to the next two pages thank you! Just a follow up question, would I need to add the web scraping portion of my code as another loop inside the first for loop since it's going to a new page each time? If the scraping loop "for e in content:" is on the outside I dont think it could scrape any data off of the first two pages right?

Comment: That is correct. You'd have to nest it as well.